# Dataweave field named "zip" how do I use it in the mapping?

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am receiving a payload as such:

```
{
  "street": "123 fake st",
  "city": "San Francisco"
  "state": "CA",
  "zip": 94117
}
```

but in my dataweave, it looks like the editor thinks that zip is a function. how to I get it to not think that? here is my dataweave:

```
Address: {
        Street: payload.address.street,
        City: payload.address.city,
        State: payload.address.state,
        Zip: payload.address.zip
    },
```

the error being listed is on the "Zip: payload.address.**zip**"

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Anirban, that configuration is working properly. Indeed when we open the DataWeave code in Studio, the **zip** field is recognized as a function. And Studio lists it as an error.

Therefore to avoid the ambiguity, I suggest to wrap it inside a single quote: `Zip: payload.address.'zip'`. No error listed anymore.

Comment: ah! that is what i am looking for thanks @sulthony h!

Answer (score 0):

I found the following example working :

```
 <flow name="application1Flow">
         <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload doc:sample="json.json"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%input payload application/json
%output application/json
---
Address:{
    Street: payload.address.street,
    City: payload.address.city,
    State: payload.address.state,
    Zip: payload.address.zip

    }]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="Payload #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

And the input request I used is :-

```
{

"address": {
    "street": "123 fake st",
    "city": "San Francisco",
    "state": "CA",
    "zip": 94117
}
```

}

I found it working :-
[image]

Comment: Correct, it works, but the editor still miss labels it. I was wondering what the escape characters are for this, or if this is just an editor bug?